# Pixel with laptop via vnc

Tags: vnc, pixel, laptop

I'm using raspberry pi 3 B and the os I'm using is PIXEL.
I'm able to use pixel by connecting it to monitor but through putty in laptop I'm unable to get the PIXEL desktop screen.
Vnc connection is not working. What should I do to make vnc work and using pixel in my laptop. Putty is working perfectly.

Comment: `PIXEL` is **NOT** an OS; PIXEL is the name of the Desktop Manager “Pi Improved Xwindows Environment, Lightweight” on the latest `Raspbian` OS. You have NOT told us what you have tried, so no one could do anything other than refer you to generic [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-pixel/), which you could do yourself.

Answer (score 1):

- Using VNC is pretty simple.
- If you have access to your monitor, simply connect it and go to Raspberry Pi Configuration from the Start Menu.
- Enable VNC and reboot.
- Once reboot, you can see VNC on the task bar.
- Update and Upgrade your Pi, reboot again.
- Assign a static IP to your Pi (recommended, optional)
- Connect your Pi to local WiFi or connect it to your computer via LAN.
- Download VNC viewer in your Computer and enter your IP address of Pi (can be seen in VNC settings or the one you assigned)
- You can enter your credentials and start working!

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the fact that you can connect to your pi via SSH your internet connection is working fine. You cannot to your pi using VNC because it is not setup up yet. You have to first enable VNC on your pi and then setup your computer to connect to your pi. Instructions for this are provided on the documentation for VNC [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/).

As Milliways has said above PIXEL is the name of the desktop manager you see on your screen, the actual operating system is Raspbian which was what you installed when you setup your pi.